# Determine days in Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to get a number of days based on ONLY 1 column of dates?
E.g., column A has dates:

```
A1 - 12/31/14
A2 - 1/1/10
A3 - 4/5/14
A4 - 12/31/12
A5 - 12/31/14
A6 - 1/8/15
```

I am trying to determine the overall days for the dates specified divided by the current date. I know in Excel I can highlight the cells and it would give me the average that I can then use a formula to determine the total days.

Comment: Are you looking for more than just counting entries?  If so, please clarify.

Comment: Why would you divide by the current date? Maybe you meant subtract the current date.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to calculate the number of days difference between a column and today's date, you can try using this formula: "=DAYS(TODAY(),*column*)"